# How can I stop Windows from switching to the international keyboard for every new program?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-layout, ime

I have multiple keyboard layouts set up for my computer so that I can type with the standard layout or with the international keyboard with support for additional characters and accent markers. However, 95% of the time I wish to use the standard layout.

But Windows keeps putting it international mode anytime I open a new program, and I have to switch back. Why is this happening and how can I change it? I don't see anything in the settings that seems like it might control this behavior.

Comment: Check `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Advanced settings` -> Override for default input method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two approaches, please notice yellow highlights:

1. **Language** control panel:

   [image]

   Following this approach, simply put your preferred settings first.
2. **Advanced options** in **Language** control panel:

   [image: Advanced Options dialog]

Each brings slightly different results. For me, reordering languages as seen in first approach is typically sufficient.

Comment: This is for Windows 10; I am on Windows 7 :(

Comment: @Aerovistae – Then use **Region and Language** control panel, press **Change Keyboards** button and set **Default input method** there. Also you can reorder installed keyboard layouts, although I am not sure at the moment whether order matters in Windows 7.

Comment: Windows keeps changing keyboard layouts and language, not clear what is the condition that produces the switch.

Comment: @ram0nvaldez – I ended using single keyboard for all the work, having uninstalled any others and that solved this problem. I was not able to find another way to fully prevent the issue you describe.